# How do you access the MAAS CLI?

Tags: maas

How do you access the MAAS CLI after new/fresh installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After you install MAAS, you must populate it with an admin account.

   `maas createadmin --username=${MAAS_USER} --password=${MAAS_PASSWORD} --email=${MAAS_EMAIL}`

---

2. Put the MAAS admin password in a read-only hidden file. (Your security requirements for password management may differ...)

   `echo ${MAAS_PASSWORD} >| /root/.maas ; chmod 600 /root/.maas`

---

3. Login to MAAS.

   `maas login ${MAAS_USER} http://localhost/MAAS/ - < /root/.maas`

---

4. Run a command to test.  For example:

   `maas ${MAAS_USER} fabrics read`